# Check an url with Alamofire : responseData don't work

Tags: swift, url, alamofire

I have a problem, I wan't to check the statusCode of an url (if the page or file exists), I want to know if the status equals to 200. So I use this function:

```
        Alamofire.request(Configuration.MyVariables.url)
            .validate(statusCode: 200)
            .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
            .responseData { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("Validation Successful")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
        }
```

But whon I debug, the program don't go inside this part: responseData { response in, I have put a wrong url, but  I can't switch on the response.

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, "9.0"

use_frameworks!

pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'GoogleConversionTracking'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'SWXMLHash'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

target 'Solutis' do

end

target 'SolutisTests' do

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON {
        response in
        guard response.result.error == nil else {
              print(response.result.error!)
            return
        }

        if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
         let status = response.response?.statusCode
           print("Validation Successful")


            do {


            }
            catch {
                print("error:\(error)")



            }
        }

    }
```

you can check response code like this:-

**response.response?.statusCode**